# Substitute Application.Getopenfilename with automation

Tags: vba

I am looking to convert the code below to one where user is not required to select the files .

This code is to select a specific sheet from all the workbooks in the specific folder say" C:\Test"

This is a part of a consolidation macro

```
sub open_issues_sheet()
Dim Files as Variant 

Files = Application.GetopenFilename("Excel FIles (*xl*),*xl*",Title:="Select Files",         Multiselect:=True)

 For Z = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
 tem=Split(Files(Z),"\")
 If(tem(UBound(tem)) <> ThisWorbook.Name) Then 

 Set S= Workbooks.Open(Files(Z))

 S.Sheets("Issues").Select
```

'code to copy to current sheet

I tried using this http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_file_names_using_vba/

but I was getting a "Type Mismatch" Error at the Line "For Z =LBound"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you still need the user to pick the folder containing the files that need to be consolidated, using the FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) would be acceptable solution.

```
Dim sFilePath As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select folder to consolidate"
    If .Show = -1 Then

        'Get the first file listed in the folder
        sFilePath = Dir(.SelectedItems(1) & "\")

        Do While Not sFilePath Like vbNullString

            'Verify the extension before opening file
            If Mid$(sFilePath, InStrRev(sFilePath, ".")) Like ".xls" Then

                ' Perform task ...

            End If

            'Get next file
            sFilePath = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With
```